# Fourier Transform of Gaussian-like function

Tags: integration, fourier-analysis

I need to find the Fourier transform of the following Gaussian-like function:

$$f(x)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi\sigma^2(x)}}\,e^{-\frac{x^2}{2\sigma^2(x)}}$$

where $\sigma(x) = \sigma_0 \sqrt{1+\left(\frac{x}{a}\right)^2}$ and $a>0$.

I know the FT of a Gaussian function, but how can I use it for calculating the FT of $f(x)$.

Comment: i have strong doubts, that closed form of this integral exists, but i really hope that i 'm wrong :)

Comment: I second @tired in believing that there is no closed-form solution to your problem.